# .jshintrc with Gulp, Jhipster

Tags: gruntjs, gulp, underscore.js, jhipster

When I want to set "Underscore" (I used to use 'Grunt') and I put in .jshintrc.

```
"globals": {
  "_": false,
```

Now with version 3.5.1 of Jhipster I use Gulp and I do not know how to configure it because there is no file .jshintrc.
Ans it gives me the error

```
angular.js:13550 ReferenceError: _ is not defined
```

Can somebody help me. Thank you.

Comment: If there is no `.jshintrc` file why don't you just create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JHipster replaced jshint with eslint in [this change](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/3007).  Because of this, you should add the globals section to the file `.eslintrc.json` the same as it was in `.jshintrc`. ([Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820817/eslints-no-undef-rule-is-calling-my-use-of-underscore-an-undefined-variable))

Based on the ReferenceError from Angular, it looks like you don't have Underscore as a dependency in your index.html.  Run `bower install underscore --save` to download and install Underscore (this adds it to bower.json), then run `gulp inject:dep` to inject the dependencies to index.html automatically.