# eslint shows error when I use my previously declared global variable

Tags: node.js, eslint

I have put a pre-commit script in my git hooks so that it uses eslint before committing the nodejs code. It analyses only the files that are to be committed. I had declare a global variable in my main entry point to my project. This is how I did it.

`global.foo = true`

The problem that I am facing now is, I am using this `foo` variable at many places in my code and without using global extension (which is valid in nodejs)

```
if(foo)
    // do somethins
else
    // do nothing
```

the code works perfectly as this is valid use of global variable. But when I commit the code, the eslint shows error on all the uses of `foo` saying that it is undeclared.

```
error  "foo" is not defined  no-undef
```

I cant think of any solution for this. Please suggest a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official [docs](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef.html) describe how you can tell eslint about globals:

```
/*global foo b:true*/
```

should do.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34820916/8081955) adds and additional way to do it

Answer (score 1):

In your `eslintrc` file add rule:

```
{
    globals: {
        'foo': true
    }
}
```