# Running script in package.json works but includes errors

Tags: node.js, npm, eslint, package.json

I just installed ESLint and I can successfully run it by doing this at the terminal window:

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint app
```

Note: `app` is the root folder I want lint to inspect.

I then put that exact command in my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint app"
  }
```

I expected to be able to run it in the terminal window like this:

```
npm run lint
```

Note: I know how to fix the no-undef error. My question is about the many errors lines after that.

It actually works, but it also produces a bunch of errors after showing me the correct output:

[image]

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default way of how the `npm` script runner handles script errors (i.e. non-zero exit codes). This will always happen, even if you only run a script like `exit 1`.

I'm not sure why this feature exists, it seems annoying and useless in most cases.

If you don't want to see this, you can add `|| true` at the end of your script.

Example:

`lint: "eslint app || true"`

*As you might've noticed, I've omitted the part to the eslint binary. The `npm` script runner already includes local binaries as part of the path when trying to run the script so there is no need to use the full path.*

Comment: Excellent tip about being able to omit the full path as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`document` is a global, so `eslint` thinks you are missing an import somewhere. For those cases, you can adapt your config so that the error is not reported, Something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  "globals": {
    "document": true
  }
}
```

this should be saved as `.eslintrc.js` and be at the same level where your `package.json` is

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the OP is asking why there is an error log when the linter fails, not how to fix the linter error.

Comment: That is correct. I know how to fix the no-undef error.

Comment: Also, that was [already answered (shamelss plug)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34820916/1276128).